# Java JDBC: Do I need to loop ResultSet when query returns single row?

Tags: java, jdbc

My sql query returns one row only. When querying, do I need to follow the usual `while(rs.next) {...}` pattern or can I do:

```
...
rs.next();
int id  = rs.getInt("id");
int age = rs.getInt("age");
String first = rs.getString("first");
String last = rs.getString("last");
...
```

Instead of:

```
...
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");
      }
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't have to loop every time since the call of `rs.next()` already sets the pointer from `null` to the first available row and returns wheather there is an entry or not.

Still it makes sense to check if something was returned at all:

```
if(rs.next())
{
    // process resultset
}else
{
    // do something when no data arrived
}
```

Comment: it may still be a good idea to use it like `if(rs.next)` though for handling the "not-found" case in the `else` block

Comment: @Selim yes you are right, if there were no entry a `NullPointerException` would be thrown.

Comment: When I expect exactly one row, I add another check it `rs.next` after grabbing values. If it returns true, I throw an exception because that means the query returned multiple rows and I don't know which one I have. This can happen when bad data is inserted, the data model changes, or the SQL is transcribed to Java incorrectly. A check like this also distinguishes from the case that you want any row. In practice, I actually use Spring's JdbcTemplate class for this. It provides several queryForObject methods that automatically provide this behavior.

Comment: @mymarkers You are correct, if you want **exactly** one row you have to call and check `rs.next()` once again. But OP asked if he can omit the while loop, not how to check that the query did **only** return one line. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of the loop if you are only interested on the first result (or there is only one). It would also be a good practice if you make sure you got some result:

```
...
if (rs.next()) {
    int id  = rs.getInt("id");
    int age = rs.getInt("age");
    String first = rs.getString("first");
    String last = rs.getString("last");
}
...
```

In any case, don't forget to close the resources no longer used (ResultSet, Statement, Connection...)