# Why is "while (rs.next())" necessary here?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to select the maximum line number from my database "*Logs*" and store it in a variable `m`.

Here's my code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select max(Line) as L from logs");

while (rs.next()) {          // Why do I need this
    int m = rs.getInt("L");
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

But it doesn't work unless I use `while(rs.next())`.

---

If I understand correctly, `rs.next(`) moves the cursor to the next row, but  here, in this result, I only have **one row**.

So, can someone explain why the loop is necessary? The only thing I can think of is that the first cursor is set on the column name, am I right?

Comment: You could just call it once, but you want to exhaust the result set just in case

Comment: If you're only expecting one row, change it to `if (rs.next())`.

Comment: @shmosel or `rs.next(); int m = rs.getInt("L");`

Comment: I'd code `if (!rs.next()) throw new Exception("something is really out of shape here")`

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690750/java-jdbc-do-i-need-to-loop-resultset-when-query-returns-single-row

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Why?

The cursor is initially placed **before** the first element. You need to **advance it once** to access the first element.

This was obviously done because traversing the results using a loop is very convenient then, as you see. From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A `ResultSet` cursor is **initially positioned before the first row**; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

---

### Solution

So, while you don't need any loop, you need to advance the cursor once. A single `rs.next();` would technically be enough:

```
rs.next();
// Access the result
```

However, you probably want to account for the case where there was no match at all, since:

> When a call to the `next` method returns `false`, the cursor is positioned after the last row. **Any invocation** of a `ResultSet` method which requires a current row will result in a `SQLException` being thrown.

So the code would fail in this case.

Because of that, you should account for the case and use the returned `boolean` to guard your access:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // Access result ...
} else {
    // No match ...
}
```

Comment: A `select max(...) ...` statement without a `group by` will always return exactly one row, even if no records match the `where` clause, in which case the returned value is `null`. So, a simple `rs.next();` is perfectly correct for this SQL.

Comment: To ensure clarity, I'd use `if(rs.first()){ ... }`. It would do exactly the same thing, but it would be much clearer to read.

Comment: @Andreas I would keep the check so the correctness of my Java is not dependent on the rules dictated by a different language. But I suppose that's personal preference. Actually I _may_ consider skipping it in a performance-critical function if the branch is really causing trouble, but only with a comment above it indicating what the assumption is. At the very least this serves as protection the next time someone alters the SQL and doesn't think to revisit the logic of the surrounding Java code.

Comment: But not here ;-)

Answer (score 23):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (which you should have read btw):

> Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

You basically need to move it, in your case moving it once is enough:

```
 rs.next(); 
 System.out.println(rs.getInt("L"));
```

Answer (score 12):

You can convert this to use a simple `if` statement instead.

```
if(rs.next()) {
    // other code here
}
```

You would use `while` when you have more than one row to bring back.

Comment: No need for the if condition just `rs.next(); int m = rs.getInt("L");` because max always return a result

Comment: @YCF_L That depends on the exact query: consider an empty table, `max` without `group by` will return a single row with `null`, but with a `group by` it will return no row

Comment: @MoritzBoth Sure, for the query in the question YCF_L is absolutely right, but given questions are - a lot of the time - simplified examples, you should consider the bigger picture as well. In this case, my response was triggered by the _always_ in YCF_L's initial comment.

Answer (score 11):

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row, the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row, the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

consider you have something like this.

```
->1->2->3
^
```

your "rs" is initially pointed before 1, when you call rs.next() it advances the arrow to point to 1

```
  ->1->2->3
    ^
```

so if you do not call the next() method then you do not get the result.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of Executing the Commands. **Cursors** are used to read the data from your executed queries. When you execute to Read, you using Forward Only Cursor by default hence you are only getting next result after calling Recorset.Next() ! I don't want to go in much deeper here. You can read about cursors here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/types-of-cursors-ado?view=sql-server-2017

The best solution in your case is to use Scalar Resultset which will return only **ONE CELL** thats exactly what you want to implement without having to loop through your result set. Following example shows how you can implement such :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class ExecuteScalar
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    SqlConnection mySqlConnection =new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee";
    mySqlConnection.Open();

    int returnValue = (int) mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() = " + returnValue);

    mySqlConnection.Close();
  }
}
```

We are using **ExecuteScalar** to return only ONE Cell. Remember, Even if your Query returns Multiple Rows/Columns, this will only returns **VERY FIRST CELL** always.

Comment: This appears to be C# code, but the question is tagged Java.